# Change color in dataGridView cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to change the ForeColor in the cell when the text is not in the correct format, I have this code to change the color after the text is entered - is this the right way?

```
private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
     dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

And how can I change it back after the user enters text in the correct format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or better use  dgv_CellValidating event. If the value is not the one you want, call the code you have up there.
And there you must have anoher event (dgv_CellEndEdit), where you set the ForeColor back to defualt one (so error will kinda dissapear).

Answer (score 2):

you can set the color back to normal in the CellValidated event handler.

Comment: your code seems to be correct, if you are getting the desired visual effect you should be good to go.

Comment: it  dos not work ,I whant if it's not in the correct format right away to be the text  red color

Comment: it depends on what you want, inside the DataError handler you can check the type of error with: if (e.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Parsing) for example, and apply red color only when the error type is the one you want to handle, not only Parsing but could be other values of the enum: DataGridViewDataErrorContexts

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be correct, if you are getting the desired visual effect you should be good to go.

same way we can change the background color also..

dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
```